# Implementing ecommerce analytics with MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, google-analytics, e-commerce, analytics

I am implementing various analytic tracking services in an MVC3 site (Google, Coremetrics) and researching if a custom HTML helper or partial view would work better given the following details:

-Code runs multiple sites and business logic is needed to change analytic service account Ids.

-The class must accept an object with order details to render the appropriate tags.

-The code must know which view is being rendered.

The solution I am working on includes am HTML helper base class that accepts the needed objects and is inherited by each provider's individual HTML helper.  These helpers will live on the common layout.  Is there a better way of implementing analytics on MVC and are partial views better suited since business logic is needed?

Answer (score 1):

The GA analytics tracking code is pretty simple, we also use ASP.NET MVC3 but have just dropped the necessary code directly into our 'Order Complete' view.

There's no reason why you couldn't use an HTML helper instead though. I suggest not overly complicating your object model. Just use a single helper that has parameters matching the parameters used in the JavaScript.

You should be able to find examples of eCommerce tracking code, add parameters as appropriate, done. You might want to create another overload that pulls GA ID and domain name from the web.config as in the example as well, but still accepts the order details as parameters.